# Divide and conquer approach in search for max element, take 2

Tags: rust

Adopted some suggestions from the answer of my [previous post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/141819/divide-and-conquer-approach-in-search-for-max-element). Here is the code:

```
trait MaxElem<T> {
    fn max_elem<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a T;
}

impl<T> MaxElem<T> for [T] where T: Ord {
    fn max_elem<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a T {
        max_elem_helper(self, 0, self.len())
    }
}


fn max_elem_helper<'a, T>(array: &'a [T], left: usize, right: usize) -> &'a T 
    where T: Ord
{
    if right - left == 1 {
        return &array[left];
    }
    let mid = (left + right) / 2;
    let max1 = max_elem_helper(array, left, mid);
    let max2 = max_elem_helper(array, mid, right);
    if max1 > max2 {
        max1
    } else {
        max2
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use max_elem::MaxElem;
    #[test]
    fn test_max_elem() {
        let array = [11, 2, 9, 1, 3, 88]; 
        let m = array.max_elem(); 
        assert_eq!(*m, 88);
    }
}
```

All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The code **panics** with a stack overflow if you provide an empty array:

   ```
   #[test]
   fn test_empty() {
       let array: [u8; 0] = [];
       array.max_elem();
   }
   ```

   ```
   thread 'test::test_empty' has overflowed its stack
   fatal runtime error: stack overflow
   error: Process didn't exit successfully: `/private/tmp/max/target/debug/max-426b0349be06fd52` (signal: 6, SIGABRT: process abort signal)
   ```
2. The tests don't work unless the crate is named `max_elem`. Instead, use `use super::MaxElem` instead.
3. You could choose to embed the helper method inside of the other function, giving a natural scoping (and preventing the need for the longer name):

   ```
   impl<T> MaxElem<T> for [T]
       where T: Ord
   {
       fn max_elem<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a T {
           fn helper<'a, T>(array: &'a [T], left: usize, right: usize) -> &'a T
               where T: Ord
           {
               // ...
           }

           helper(self, 0, self.len())
       }
   }
   ```
4. Instead of passing in the entire slice and left / right; try splitting the slice into smaller parts via `split_at`. Then the slice itself tracks the beginning and the end.
5. The function [`cmp::max`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/fn.max.html) exists.

---

Overall, there's a nice functional implementation that weighs-in at about 20 lines.

```
use std::cmp;

trait MaxElem<T> {
    fn max_elem<'a>(&'a self) -> Option<&'a T>;
}

impl<T> MaxElem<T> for [T] where T: Ord {
    fn max_elem<'a>(&'a self) -> Option<&'a T> {
        let len = self.len();

        match len {
            0 | 1 => self.first(),
            _ => {
                let mid = len / 2;
                let (left, right) = self.split_at(mid);

                let left = left.max_elem();
                let right = right.max_elem();

                match (left, right) {
                    (Some(a), Some(b)) => Some(cmp::max(a, b)),
                    _ => left.or(right)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use super::MaxElem;

    #[test]
    fn test_max_elem() {
        let array = [11, 2, 9, 1, 3, 88];
        assert_eq!(Some(&88), array.max_elem());
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_empty() {
        let array: [u8; 0] = [];
        assert_eq!(None, array.max_elem());
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the slice is passed by reference, size shouldn't really matter, right?

Comment: @qed which "size" are you referring to? A slice is a *fat pointer*; it contains the start of the data and a length, so it takes 2 `usize` worth of space. The `helper` method doubles that, requiring a total of 4 `usize`s.

Comment: Looks lovely. :-)