# Insertion sort in Rust

Tags: rust, insertion-sort

Here is the code:

```
pub fn insertion_sort<T>(vec: &mut Vec<T>) where T: Ord + Copy {
    fn insert<U>(vec: &mut Vec<U>, pos: usize, value: U) where U: Ord + Copy {
        assert!(pos > 0);
        let mut pos: usize = pos - 1;
        loop {
            let value_at_pos = vec[pos]; 
            if value_at_pos <= value {
                break;
            }
            vec[pos + 1] = value_at_pos; 
            if pos == 0 {
                vec[pos] = value;
                return ();
            }
            pos -= 1;
        }
        vec[pos + 1] = value;
    }
    for i in 1..vec.len() {
        let value = vec[i];
        insert(vec, i, value);
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_insertion_sort() {
    let mut vec = vec![9, 8, 7, 11, 10]; 
    insertion_sort(&mut vec);
    let vec_res: Vec<_> = (7..12).collect();
    assert_eq!(vec, vec_res);
}
```

It's slightly more complex than in textbooks due to the fact negative integers are not allowed for indexing in Rust, not a huge problem though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. As [you have already been made aware](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/141829/32521), you should **not** be using `&mut Vec<T>` unless you plan on adding or removing items from the `Vec`. Using `&mut [T]` better expresses the contract of the function *and* is more flexible, allowing you to also sort arrays and anything else that can be expressed as a slice.
2. `where` clauses go on a separate line. This allows them to be easily found, which is important considering how much they affect the behavior of the function.
3. There's no need to declare the type of `pos`. Type inference will take care of it.
4. There's no need to redeclare `pos` just to make it mutable and decrement it. Just make the variable binding in the function declaration `mut`.
5. There's no need to return the unit value (`()`). Just `return` will suffice.
6. [`slice::swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.swap) exists. In the broader world, so does [`mem::swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.swap.html).
7. With the power of `swap`, you can remove the need for the `Copy` bound.
8. [Quickcheck](https://github.com/BurntSushi/quickcheck) is an invaluable tool for problems like this. You can create a *property* that can be validated across a wide range of automatically generated input.

```
pub fn insertion_sort<T>(values: &mut [T])
    where T: Ord
{
    for i in 0..values.len() {
        for j in (0..i).rev() {
            if values[j] >= values[j + 1] {
                values.swap(j, j + 1);
            } else {
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

#[macro_use]
extern crate quickcheck;

#[test]
fn test_insertion_sort_empty() {
    let mut values: [i32; 0] = [];
    insertion_sort(&mut values);
    assert_eq!(values, [])
}

#[test]
fn test_insertion_sort_one() {
    let mut values = [1];
    insertion_sort(&mut values);
    assert_eq!(values, [1]);
}

#[test]
fn test_insertion_multi() {
    let mut values = [9, 8, 7, 11, 10];
    insertion_sort(&mut values);
    let values_expected: Vec<_> = (7..12).collect();
    assert_eq!(values_expected, values);
}

quickcheck! {
    fn test_insertion_everything(xs: Vec<i32>) -> bool {
        // Macro doesn't allow `mut` in the `fn` declaration :-(
        let mut xs = xs;

        let mut expected_sorted = xs.clone();
        expected_sorted.sort();

        insertion_sort(&mut xs);

        expected_sorted == xs
    }
}
```