# Heap sort in Rust

Tags: sorting, rust, heap-sort

The tests are taken from [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/142070/118470) on an *insertion sort in rust* question.

The algorithm is taken from *Algorithms in a Nutshell (2nd Edition)*.

I'm not looking at crazy performance, the goal being to learn about basic algorithms and rust, but if there is something shockingly inefficient please let me know.

```
fn main() {}

fn heapify<T>(slice: &mut [T], idx: usize, max: usize)
    where T: Ord
{
    let mut largest = idx;
    let left = idx*2 + 1;
    let right = idx*2 + 2;

    if left < max && slice[left] > slice[largest] {
        largest = left;
    }

    if right < max && slice[right] > slice[largest] {
        largest = right;
    }

    if largest != idx {
        slice.swap(largest, idx);
        heapify(slice, largest, max);
    }
}

fn heap_sort<T>(slice: &mut [T])
    where T: Ord
{
    let len = slice.len();
    if len <= 1 {
        return;
    }
    for i in (0..len/2).rev() {
        heapify(slice, i, len);
    }
    for i in (1..len).rev() {
        slice.swap(0, i);
        heapify(slice, 0, i);
    }
}

#[macro_use]
extern crate quickcheck;

#[test]
fn test_heapify() {
    let mut values = [8, 11, 9, 2, 10, 16];
    heapify(&mut values, 2, 6);
    assert_eq!(values, [8, 11, 16, 2, 10, 9]);
    heapify(&mut values, 1, 6);
    assert_eq!(values, [8, 11, 16, 2, 10, 9]);
    heapify(&mut values, 0, 6);
    assert_eq!(values, [16, 11, 9, 2, 10, 8]);

}

#[test]
fn test_heap_sort_empty() {
    let mut values: [i32; 0] = [];
    heap_sort(&mut values);
    assert_eq!(values, [])
}

#[test]
fn test_heap_sort_one() {
    let mut values = [1];
    heap_sort(&mut values);
    assert_eq!(values, [1]);
}

#[test]
fn test_heap_multi() {
    let mut values = [9, 8, 7, 11, 10];
    heap_sort(&mut values);
    let values_expected: Vec<_> = (7..12).collect();
    assert_eq!(values_expected, values);
}

quickcheck! {
    fn test_heap_everything(xs: Vec<i32>) -> bool {
        // Macro doesn't allow `mut` in the `fn` declaration :-(
        let mut xs = xs;
        let mut expected_sorted = xs.clone();
        expected_sorted.sort();
        heap_sort(&mut xs);
        expected_sorted == xs
    }
}
```